# How can I use SetEnv with mod_fcgid to pass virtualhost specific options to my PHP application? (apache2)

Tags: php, apache-2.2, mod-fcgid, setenv

I'm running into some trouble figuring out how I should handle something under FastCGI that worked pretty easily under mod_php. Before I was using `SetEnv` to pass options from my VirtualHost directive to my PHP application. For example:

```
SetEnv MYAPP_LOGGING_ROOT "/usr/local/myapp/logs"
```

I was able to access this value from `$_SERVER['MYAPP_LOGGING_ROOT']` and it was a pretty convenient way to do manage this. However, this value is not being passed to my PHP application in a FastCGI environment.

I tried the following but it does not appear to be passing all the way down to my PHP application either:

```
FcgidInitialEnv MYAPP_LOGGING_ROOT "/usr/local/myapp/logs"
```

Am I missing something simple or do I need to be doing something more complex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SetEnv work with mod-fcgid. My config:

```
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
            FCGIWrapper /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5
            AddHandler fcgid-script .php
            Options ExecCGI Indexes
            SetEnv MYAPP_LOGGING_ROOT "/usr/local/myapp/logs"
    </Directory>
```

foo.php:

```
<?php
    var_dump($_SERVER["MYAPP_LOGGING_ROOT"]);
?>
```

Test:

```
curl localhost/foo.php 
string(21) "/usr/local/myapp/logs"
```

Comment: Your answer encouraged me to do some more debugging and found that there was an error elsewhere in my code that was obscuring my original SetEnv command.